# Cycles Color Problem

Tags: cycles-render-engine, color

I have a problem with colors in Cycles. Instead of yellow it renders pink, Anyone knows what to do?

https://pasteall.org/blend/67711b6e92f64b8baa804d282cd9fe7d

[image]
[image]

Comment: are you sure the faces have the right material?

Comment: What did you do between those screenshots? Switched from Eevee to Cycles? When you switch back (not using undo with CTRL+Z) does the color revert to yellow?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add different materials to different parts of a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh)

Comment: Agree with moonboots, make sure each material is properly assigned to the mesh, see the linked answer....

Comment: put the file....

Comment: Markus von Broady yes, I just switched  between those two engines, and yes when I switch between them back it changes again

Comment: brockmann, well it have to be properly assigned because whenever I change this in evie everything is fine

Comment: please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/67711b6e92f64b8baa804d282cd9fe7d

Answer (score 3):

This might be a lighting problem. Do you have a colored light in your scene?
If none of your lights contain any Yellow, only the other colors will be reflected by the Material

EDIT:

I figured it out.
The part with the problem has multiple surfaces inside of each other.

I dragged them apart and apparently this part exists 8 times. With the pink material on 6 of the instances.

[image]

This sometimes happens unnoticed, when proportional editing is turned on, because it makes you move all the objects at once.

Proportional editing (for those who don't know) is this option:

[image]

Turn it off, point at the problematic part, hit L and then drag your selection away and you will see.
;)

Comment: I checked and I think this is not the case

Comment: if you can provide a .blend file I (and others) might be able to take a closer look at the problem.

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/67711b6e92f64b8baa804d282cd9fe7d

Comment: I got it, I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for help :D